# How to replace datetime in var list with date linq

Tags: c#, linq, date

I have a var list i created in a query , there is a field called Fecha that stores a datetime , i want just to store the date, but if i run the property Date inside the linq query it says it can't recognize the method so i have to do it after the list is created.

```
using (ProfesionalesEmpresasEntities bd = new ProfesionalesEmpresasEntities())
{

    var resultado = (from registroLlamadas in bd.RegistroLlamadas
                    join contacto in bd.Contactos on registroLlamadas.realizadaHacia equals contacto.id
                    select new { Fecha = registroLlamadas.fechaLlamada }).
                    ToList();    
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error ?

Comment: You might want to scale back your indenting for better readability.

Comment: Why not,  Fetcha = registroLlamadas.fechaLlamada.Date

Comment: Either use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime or SqlFunctions.DatePart  instead of the Date property.

Answer (score 2):

You can only specify `Date` property on LINQ to object query, Since you have already iterated your query using `ToList` you can do that after like:

```
var resultado = (from registroLlamadas in bd.RegistroLlamadas
    join contacto in bd.Contactos on registroLlamadas.realizadaHacia equals contacto.id
    select new
    {

        Fecha = registroLlamadas.fechaLlamada

    }).AsEnumerable() //Bring it in memory or leave it as `ToList`
    .Select(row => new
    {

        Fecha = row.Fecha.Date,

    }).ToList();
```

or if you don't want to modify your current query or mix query/method expression, then use your existing `resultado` object like:

```
resultado = resultado.Select(r=> new { Fecha = r.Fecha.Date }).ToList();
```